# Eigenvalue for the creation operator for a coherent state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, hilbert-space, eigenvalue

For a coherent state 
$$
|\alpha\rangle=e^{-\frac{|\alpha|^{2}}{2}}\sum_{n}\frac{\alpha^{n}}{\sqrt{n!}}|n\rangle
$$
I can't solve the eigenvalue problem for $\hat{a}^{\dagger}|\alpha\rangle$ where $\hat{a}^{\dagger}$ is the creation operator. I can only get this far

$$
\begin{align}
\hat{a}^{\dagger}|\alpha\rangle&=e^{-\frac{|\alpha|^{2}}{2}}\sum_{n}\frac{\alpha^{n}}{\sqrt{n!}}\hat{a}^{\dagger}|n\rangle\\
&=e^{-\frac{|\alpha|^{2}}{2}}\sum_{n}\frac{\alpha^{n}}{\sqrt{n!}}\sqrt{n+1}|n+1\rangle
\end{align}
$$

Ultimately, I want to calculate $\langle \alpha |a\hat{a}^{\dagger}|\alpha\rangle$, but I don't know $\hat{a}^{\dagger}|\alpha\rangle$.

Comment: You know the result that a creation operator acts on an eigenstate $|n>$, then, just sum over all the results.

Comment: I did. But then, I stuck from there afterward.

Comment: @qfzklm does the result simplify much? e.g. is the resulting sum a well-known one?

Comment: @TBBT what result do you expect to find? $|\alpha\rangle$ isn't an eigenfunction of the creation operator - you won't find something $\propto |\alpha\rangle$. Do you want to know whether the sum simplifies?

Comment: I want to calculate this, $\langle\alpha|aa^{\dagger}|\alpha\rangle$. But I don't know what $a^{\dagger}|\alpha\rangle$ is.

Comment: @TBBT try using commutation relations to get an $a |\alpha \rangle$?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A coherent state is, amongst other interesting things, an eigenstate of the *annihilation* operator. It is not an eigenstate of the creation operator; hence, I'm not sure this "eigenvalue problem" makes much sense.

This is easy to realize. You can quickly see that $\langle0|a^\dagger|\alpha\rangle=0$, whereas $\langle0|\alpha\rangle\neq0$.

If you really want to find $\langle \alpha | a a^\dagger|\alpha\rangle
$ in e.g. 
$$
\langle x^2 \rangle \propto \langle \alpha | (a+a^\dagger)(a+a^\dagger)|\alpha\rangle
$$
you can commute the operators $a$ and $a^\dagger$ with the rule $[a,a^\dagger] = 1$, such that
$$
\langle \alpha | a a^\dagger|\alpha\rangle = \langle \alpha | a^\dagger a|\alpha\rangle + 1 = 1 + |\alpha|^2
$$
You can also verify this the long way around by acting the the operators.

Comment: You are correct. However, I can't still calculate, $\langle\alpha|aa^{\dagger}|\alpha\rangle$. I have to solve something in my homework that look like this,$\langle\alpha|aa|\alpha\rangle+\langle\alpha|a^{\dagger}a^{\dagger}|\alpha\rangle+\langle\alpha|aa^{\dagger}|\alpha\rangle+\langle\alpha|a^{\dagger}a|\alpha\rangle$

Comment: I can solve three out of four terms above, but not the $\langle\alpha|aa^{\dagger}|\alpha\rangle$

Comment: I think that's quite straight-forward - just commute the operators. See my edited answer.

Comment: Wow, can't believe I couldn't see that. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 13):

To add to [Innisfree's correct answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/205982/26076), I'd like to emphasize something that the OP does not seem to know and that is that the creation operator has *no* eigenvectors (nor, therefore, eigenvalues). It is easy to see this: write a general state as a row vector $(\psi_0,\,\psi_1,\,\cdots)$ of superposition weights for the number states $|0\rangle,\,|1\rangle,\,\cdots$ and in this notation, our eigenvalue equation (in $\lambda$) for $a^\dagger$ is:

$$a^\dagger (\psi_0,\,\psi_1,\,\cdots) =(0,\,\psi_0,\,\sqrt{2} \psi_1,\,\sqrt{3} \psi_2,\,\cdots) =  \lambda (\psi_0,\,\psi_1,\,\cdots)$$

whence we get $\lambda \,\psi_n=\sqrt{n}\psi_{n-1}$ and $\lambda\,\psi_0=0$. If $\lambda = 0$ it follows straight away that $\psi_n=0\,\forall\,n\in\mathbb{N}$. If $\lambda\neq 0$, then $\psi_0=0$, whence (by induction through $\psi_n = \sqrt{n}\psi_{n-1}/\lambda$) $\psi_n=0\,\forall\,n\in\mathbb{N}$. There is therefore no normalizable superposition of number states that is an eigenvector for $a^\dagger$. It's therefore not surprising that the OP was having difficulty!

Comment: This is also in my answer ;) it is the same as the comment "You can quickly see..."

Comment: @innisfree  Ah, sorry, I missed that. I just wanted to emphasize a bit more to the OP (because I can recall at one stage assuming that the creation operator would have an eigenvector). Doubtless he/she will remember the nonexistence of creation operator eigenvectors after today.

Comment: No worries, it is helpful that you stressed it a bit more than I did.

Comment: "you can quickly see" is good, but sometimes it's helpful to have things spelled out fully. I found this answer useful.

Answer (score 3):

Using the definition of the creation operator, $a^\dagger = c(m\omega \hat x - i\hat p)$ where $c$ is a constant, and $\hat p = -i\hbar\partial_x$, you can write the eigenvalue problem in the position representation as $$(m\omega x - \hbar\partial_x)\psi = \alpha\psi.$$
You can solve this differential equation to find $$\psi = C\exp(m\omega x^2/\hbar - \alpha x/\hbar)$$
which is clearly not normalizable. Hence the creation operator has no normalizable eigenstates.